# Leads in partner central community

Tags: partner-communities, lightning-community

We are using the Partner Central community at a customer and have some issue with the display of a converted Lead. Basically this looks the same as a non converted lead but in a kind of read-only mode => no actions available, no edit button, no chatter,...

In the classic partner community (using VF +Tabs) this was more obvious because there you see a screen that says the lead has been converted and a link to the account + opportunity.

Can we somehow get a similar behavior in the Partner Central community? Or what is the best practice approach here?